# Recover root password from terminal

Tags: macos, recovery, root

So, how can I recover password of root account using only terminal?
I have only terminal (not sudo), and no GUI acces

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall the OS, or restore it from a backup. How did you get into that mess?

Comment: Eh, I made new password that is 8 characters long with @# symbols because I thought my old password is not enough secure, than I made everything wrong, and now I have only terminal...

Comment: When you say 'root' account, do you mean the root user, or just an admin account? Normally root shouldn't be enabled.

Comment: I am new at mac, I thought if I get root access, I can go to passwords file and know my password like in Linux

Comment: In general you cannot "recover" the password (as in knowing what the password originally were)... however you can set a new password. Is that what you want?

Comment: Even in Linux you can't get your password from the password file, only its hashed value.